# Execute Mathematical operations in a protected file

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have an Excel file where i've got unprottected cells to put data and then protected cells where I execute a mathematical operations for example =A1+A2/A3.

But then when I write in the unprottected cells A1,A2 and A3 the protected cell with the mathematical operations does not execute, but i need that cell being protected to avoid any user change that operation.

¿Can you help me please?

Comment: You should check if Calculation in your workbook is set to Automatic. Go to the Formula tab and look for calculation options (should be pretty far to the right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Angad for your aswer it's what i was doing but my problem was solved by going to FORMULAS --> Calculation options and the changing to automatic instead of manual.

If it's on manual you have to press intro into the protected cell and because you can't do that you can't operate.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the above question I understood you need to perform an operation like this A1+B1=C1, where A1 & B1 are editable fields and C1 should not be editable.

To do this please follow the below steps

1. Please enter the formula in cell C1, A1+B1. You can also increase
   the range from C1 to C100
2. Select the cells which you want to lock, i.e. C1 to C100 and right-click and select Format-Cell (shortcut is ctrl+1)
3. Go to last protection tab and click the checkbox Locked
4. Now select A1 to B100 range and right click and again select format-cell and go to protection tab and make sure locked checkbox must be unchecked.
5. Now go to Review tab and select protect sheet option
6. enter the password and confirm the password and save the changes
7. With this, you are able to edit the cells A1 to B100 but you can't edit the cell C1 to C100 and C1 to C100 contains the sum of A1 to B100 respectively.